# What type of data can I pull from an iPhone?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ipad, analytics

I have analytics on my phone to get some use info.  Right now I get info such as UDID, iOS Version, and hardware version.  But what else can I pull?

Comment: address book, location data, usage statistics, ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a specialist analytics package such as [Flurry](http://www.flurry.com/) and you will be provided with a wealth of usage and user information.